# Get max top 10 element in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, max

I have an array something like that and I want to sort by population property.

```
const countries = [
{"name":"Burkina Faso",population:19034397},
{"name":"Burundi",population:10114505}
...
]
```

Then I want to get top max 10 object with name and property into something like that

```
const data = {
  labels=[<country names>]
  datasets:[
  {data:[<population numbers>]}
 ]  
}
```

I tried some code

```
const sortItem = () => {
    let arr =[]
    let values = dataSource.map(item => arr.push({name:item.name,population:item.population}))
    let topValues = values.sort((a,b) => b.population-a.population);
    console.log(topValues) // output 1,2,3,4,5...
  }
```

But I can't get what I want. How can I achieve the solution ?

Comment: Did any part of it work, like the sorting? Or are you just trying to get the top 10?

Comment: My goal is to get the top 10